# What does gravity being dynamical mean?

Tags: gravity

My confusion arose while studying two dimensional models of quantum gravity, in particular the well-studied Jackiw-Teitelboim gravity model in the holographic context. Is it correct to say that the JT gravity model is a theory of dynamical gravity? My naive understanding is that in two and three dimensions there are no propagating degrees of freedom in the gravitational field, so in what sense should we call a theory of gravity "dynamical"?